# Coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1-x^m)^{-1}(1-x^{m-1})^{-1}\ldots(1-x)^{-1}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Is it possible to compute a closed form solution for the coefficient of $x^n$ in

$$(1-x^m)^{-1}(1-x^{m-1})^{-1}\ldots(1-x)^{-1}$$

Comment: It's the number of ways of partitioning $n$ into integers at most $m$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Generating_function

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I went through the wiki page. This part of the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts provides a recurrence relation to compute this coefficient practically, however there is no general formula which takes $n$ and $m$ and computes the coefficient. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I think that's a reasonable way to put it.